# Why are the images not being displayed?

Tags: java, swing, awt

[image]    package main;

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.DisplayMode;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.RenderingHints;

import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class ImageTest extends JFrame {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    DisplayMode displayMode;

    if (args.length == 3) {
        displayMode = new DisplayMode(Integer.parseInt(args[0]),
                Integer.parseInt(args[1]), Integer.parseInt(args[2]),
                DisplayMode.REFRESH_RATE_UNKNOWN);
    } else {
        displayMode = new DisplayMode(800, 600, 16,
                DisplayMode.REFRESH_RATE_UNKNOWN);
    }

    ImageTest test = new ImageTest();
    test.run(displayMode);
}

private SimpleScreenManager screen;
private boolean imagesLoaded;

private Image bgImage;
private Image opaqueImage;
private Image transparentImage;
private Image translucentImage;
private Image antiAliasedImage;

private void run(DisplayMode displayMode) {
    setBackground(Color.blue);
    setForeground(Color.white);
    setFont(new Font("Dialog", Font.PLAIN, 24));
    imagesLoaded = false;
    screen = new SimpleScreenManager();
    try {
        screen.setFullScreen(displayMode, this);
        loadImages();

        try {
            Thread.sleep(10000);
        } catch (Exception e) {

        }
    } catch (Exception e) {

    } finally {
        screen.restoreScreen();
    }
}

private void loadImages() {
    bgImage = loadImage("/images/background.png");
    opaqueImage = loadImage("/images/opaque.png");
    transparentImage = loadImage("/images/transparent.png");
    translucentImage = loadImage("/images/translucent.png");
    antiAliasedImage = loadImage("/images/antialiased.png");
    imagesLoaded = true;
    repaint();
}

private Image loadImage(String fileName) {
    return new ImageIcon(fileName).getImage();

}

public void paint(Graphics g) {
    if (g instanceof Graphics2D) {
        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
        g2.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_TEXT_ANTIALIASING,
                RenderingHints.VALUE_TEXT_ANTIALIAS_ON);
    }

    g.drawImage(opaqueImage, 0, 0, this);

    if (imagesLoaded) {
        g.drawImage(bgImage, 0, 0, null);
        drawImage(g, opaqueImage, 0, 0, "Opaque");
        drawImage(g, transparentImage, 320, 0, "Transparent");
        drawImage(g, translucentImage, 0, 300, "Translucent");
        drawImage(g, antiAliasedImage, 320, 300,
                "Translucent (Anti-Aliased)");
    } else {
        g.drawString("Loading Images...", 5, 24);
    }
}

public void drawImage(Graphics g, Image image, int x, int y, String caption) {

    g.drawImage(image, x, y, this);
    g.drawString(caption, x + 5, y + 24 + image.getHeight(null));

}
}
```

There are no errors!, the program runs, it displays the text, but not the images.  Which means that loadImages() works, it must be a mistake in my paint method.  What am I doing wrong!?!?

I don't see what is wrong with my path:
[image]

Comment: Absolute path error? Are those valid paths to the images?

Comment: yes, thoes are the correct paths for images.

Comment: I tried doing what I usually do:
`(ImageIcon ii = new ImageIcon(this.getClass().getResource(path));
Image i = ii.getImage();
g.drawImage(i, 0, 0, this);`
it works perfectly fine

Comment: Try without the leading back slash.

Comment: @Steven : Please have a look at this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9866659/1057230), hopefully that might be able to help :-)

Comment: This works!

Thank you.

This is still bothering me though, because I don't understand what is wrong with my code. nonetheless, I got it working. thank you :P

Comment: @Steven : I personally keep myself away from IDEs, since I am a learner, so can not tell you exactly which IDE you are using. But I can give you a small hint, in quick words :-) "When you write `getClass().getResource("/images/background.png")` now the first forward slash means that the images folder should reside alongside `main` folder (which is the package containing .class files or sub-packages), though if you will take the first forward slash out and write `getClass().getResource("images/background.png")` it means that images folder must be present next to the `.class` file which"

Comment: __Continued...__ : contains this code literal :-). I hope you understood :-) how this thingy is working now :-) For the rest You're MOST WELCOME and KEEP SMILING :-) and yeah, please do add `@` before posting a comment to someone, else the message won't reach that person's inbox ever :( Do watch the last link in those links, I had posted as an answer, that gives you the directory structure too, in the comments of the code provided, for you to understand that a bit more better :-)

Comment: @nIcE cOw: I understand what you are saying.  I posted a stack question a while back because an image wasn't displaying and the slash was the issue.  I tried it both with and without the slash.  I get the same result, but thank you. What you said makes sense.  I will definitely use it for future reference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you take a look at the `ImageIcon` source you will notice that the `ImageIcon(String)` constructor calls another constructor

```
ImageIcon(String filename, String description) {
    image = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage(filename);
    if (image == null) {
        return;
   }
   this.filename = filename;
   this.description = description;
   loadImage(image);
}
```

and `.getImage()`

```
public Image getImage() {
     return image;
}
```

If it fails to load an image that image will simply be null without throwing any errors. Your code fails (silently) to load the image (check this with a `System.out.println(image)` most likely because of an incorrect filepath.

Edit to your comments: I prefer `ImageIO` to load my files feeding it an inputstream. It is more verbose and has the added benefit of letting me load files from within jars. Change

```
private Image loadImage(String fileName) {
     return new ImageIcon(fileName).getImage();
}
```

to

```
private Image loadImage(String fileName) {
     return ImageIO.read(getClass().getResourceAsStream(fileName));
}
```

Comment: I don't see what is wrong with my path :/
also I tried it with and without / before the path

Comment: when I try the system.out.print...

I get this

`null
null
sun.awt.image.ToolkitImage@2e378b91
sun.awt.image.ToolkitImage@2e378b91
sun.awt.image.ToolkitImage@2e378b91
`

Comment: it appears as it is initially null, then get's the image later